# Good reason to continue using fraudulent certificate?

Tags: certificates, web-browser, certificate-revocation

A relative of mine used a favorites link to login to yahoo. The favorite link is

```
https://de.mg40.mail.yahoo.com/neo/launch?
```

However, this link uses a fraudulent certificate. Visiting the Yahoo website was now (maybe 2 weeks ago) reported as insecure (you can try above link). However, when redirected from the main yahoo.de website to a different server, Yahoo already uses a newer certificate which is not fraudulent.

What is a good reason to keep a fraudulent certificate and not replace it by a renewed one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate is not necessarily fraudulent (though it does expire on the 28th of March) as much as it is that the name being used to access the resource doesn't match what is on the certificate.

It's common for companies to have aliases or CNAMES for services/hosts. The problem is that unless you generate a UCG or SANS cert to handle all the names then you can run into the situation that you are experiencing.

With all that being said, it is very bad practice for a company not to accommodate for this when modifying their infrastructure as the Common Name on a certificate is the defining security characteristic of an SSL certificate.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's my mistake. I looked up non-trustful certificates in Internet Explorer and it showed login.yahoo.com by UTN-USERFirst-Hardware, expiring 2014-03-15 which was reported as fraudulent. But you're right, the one I mentioned in my question expires on 2014-03-28, so they are different ones. I guess that answers my question.